# Dataframe to Dictionary, with all same column values within a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as such:

```
Year     Name       Details
2009     Apple       Red
2010     Banana      Yellow
2010     Grape       Purple
```

I'd like to go from df to dict that looks as such:

```
{{'2009': 
    {'Name': 'Apple', 'Details' : 'Red'}
 }
 {'2010': 
    {'Name': 'Banana', 'Details' : 'Yellow'},
    {'Name': 'Grape', 'Details' : 'Purple'}
  }
}
```

Basically every row that has the same 'year' value is in a dictionary nested within it's year. I've tried iterating through the df using

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
```

however only the last row iteration seems to stick.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So a dictionary where the key is the year and it contains a list of dictionaries with name and details as keys, right?

Comment: Yes that's the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `to_dict` twice

```
df.groupby('Year').apply(lambda s: s.drop('Year', 1).to_dict('records')).to_dict()
```

or use a dict comprehension

```
{year: sub.to_dict('records') for year, sub in df.groupby('Year')}
```

---

```
{2009: [{'Details': 'Red', 'Name': 'Apple'}],
 2010: [{'Details': 'Yellow', 'Name': 'Banana'},
  {'Details': 'Purple', 'Name': 'Grape'}]}
```

Comment: @Steel forgot to add the `.drop('Year', 1)` as in the other soution. Complete code: `{year: sub.drop('Year', 1).to_dict('records') for year, sub in df.groupby('Year')}`